# Gigya initialize crash

Tags: android, gigya

I'm implementing gigya in a project but I'm getting the following crash in some devices:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: com/gigya/socialize/android/login/providers/GooglePlusProvider
                                                                     at com.gigya.socialize.android.login.LoginProviderFactory.<init>(LoginProviderFactory.java:26)
                                                                     at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAPI.initialize(GSAPI.java:380)
                                                                     at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAPI.initialize(GSAPI.java:358)
```

After debugging the LoginProviderFactory.class I found out that the following method: GooglePlusProvider.isConfigured() is crashing the app.

Again, this happens just on some phones, for example a Samsung Galaxy s4 mini.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

EDIT:
More debbuging shows this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gigya.socialize.android.login.providers.GooglePlusProvider
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include google play services into you build.gradle?

Comment: Yes I included Google play services in my app but it seems that different Android versions merge manifest/ dependencies declarations in a different way.My app contains multiple modules and the gradle file that included the services library was in a different module , Gigya was unable to grab the library on the fly. I modified the gradle.build arrangement between my modules and everything works fine.